# Express 4 route won't hit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.listen(9000);

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("not being hit");
    res.send(200);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("always hits");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

This seems like such a simple problem but my brain is starting to turn to mush.

Here's the details:

I have `run build` on a react app and the `index.html` file resides in the build folder, and I want this served via express.

I want express to prioritize `/test` first, and if it's not `/test`, then I want it to serve the `index.html` file in the build folder.

If you go to `/test`, it is skipped and always hits the `/*` route. If you remove the wild card and use `/` instead, neither routes will hit if you go to `/` or `/test` in the browser. However, `index.html` is still served and it looks like that's because of the static middleware.

Everything I have read suggests that order in express is important, but I feel like I'm losing my damn mind and I'm starting to slowly descend into madness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the deployment URL? `localhost:900`?

Comment: try commenting out , express static and /* routes. Then hit /test and see if it works

Comment: @AdamAzad `localhost:9000`

Comment: Try what @ssk suggested.

Comment: @ssk /test works under this condition

Comment: now introduce /* as a catch all, and see that /test hits first route only. Feels like express static is the culprit here.

Comment: @ssk looks like you're right - it will hit both routes now. However, `index.html` can't load its static assets, obviously. How can I include that without breaking the routes?

Comment: From what I looked up, it looks like my placement is already ideal? If express reads this in order, then technically my static middleware shouldn't be affecting the route above it. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: I just tested it, `http://localhost:9000/test` works as expected. Something else must be wrong with your project/config.

Comment: Interesting... Maybe I'm not as nuts as I thought. I built this project to simulate the same issue in a larger project and got the same results. Not sure what the hell is going on here, but that is useful information. Thank you.

Comment: Routes are matched in the order they are registered so neither the `express.static()` or `app.get('/*', ...)` routes will stop the `app.get('/test', ...)` route from matching.  Like others have said, if this isn't working for you, then there's something else going on that you aren't showing us.